# Why not post data with file_get_contents PHP function?

Tags: php, post, file-get-contents

I'm sorry, I speak a little English.

I read it all here. Why not works? No post data.

Edited (with Content-type):

```
$postdata = http_build_query( array(

    'request'=> 'activate',
    'license-key'=> $_POST [ 'license-key' ],
    'http_host'=> $_SERVER [ 'HTTP_HOST' ],
    'wp_version'=> $wp_version,
    'theme_version'=> $theme_version

) );

$opts = array( 'http'=> array(

    'method'=> 'POST',
    'header'=> 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'content'=> $postdata

) );

$context = stream_context_create( $opts );

$json = file_get_contents( 'https://test2.com/api', false, $context ); // https://test2.com/api/index.php
```

https://test2.com/api

```
$postdata = json_encode( $_POST );
$sql = "INSERT INTO `api`( `request`, `postdata`, `return` ) VALUES( '" . $_POST [ 'request' ] . "', '" . $postdata . "', 'success' )";
```

The database:

```
INSERT INTO `api`( `request`, `postdata`, `return` ) VALUES( '', '[]', 'success' );
```

Why empty the request and postdata columns? The return column is okay.

error_log

```
[28-Jul-2021 16:25:12 America/New_York] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: request in /home/*/public_html/api/index.php on line 15
```

The 14-15. line:

```
$postdata = json_encode( $_POST );
$sql = "INSERT INTO `api`( `request`, `postdata`, `return` ) VALUES( '" . $_POST [ 'request' ] . "', '" . $postdata . "', 'success' )";
```

Log:

```
162.0.235.*** - - [28/Jul/2021:16:01:09 -0400] "POST /api HTTP/1.0" 301 707 "-" "-"
162.0.235.*** - - [28/Jul/2021:16:01:09 -0400] "GET /api/ HTTP/1.0" 200 20 "-" "-"
162.0.235.*** - - [28/Jul/2021:16:03:38 -0400] "POST /api HTTP/1.0" 301 707 "-" "-"
162.0.235.*** - - [28/Jul/2021:16:03:38 -0400] "GET /api/ HTTP/1.0" 200 20 "-" "-"
162.0.235.*** - - [28/Jul/2021:16:07:07 -0400] "POST /api HTTP/1.0" 301 707 "-" "-"
162.0.235.*** - - [28/Jul/2021:16:07:07 -0400] "GET /api/ HTTP/1.0" 200 20 "-" "-"
```

Please help me.

Comment: You forgot the `Content-type` header.

Comment: Dear Barmar, It not works.

Comment: Do you have the `fopen_url` setting enabled in `php.ini`?

Comment: The phpinfo() allow_url_fopen: On/On

Comment: Then I can't think of any reason why it doesn't work. Does it work if you use `curl` instead?

Comment: I would like use file_get_contents.

Comment: Why close my question? I don't understand.

Comment: because the other question shows how to send a POST request with `file_get_contents`.

Comment: I know what you want to do. I asked you to try that as an experiment. Maybe something else is blocking you.

Comment: I would like this: $sql = "INSERT INTO `api`( `request`, `postdata`, `return` ) VALUES( '" . $_POST [ 'request' ] . "', '" . json_encode( $_POST ) . "', 'success' )"; The insert is okay and the 'success' is okay, but the `request` and the `postdata` not, empty.

Comment: Are you saying that the POST request is being sent, but some of the parameters are missing? Why didn't you say that in the question?>

Comment: Not solving my problem. I read all questions in stackoverflow. I don't understand, why close my question if not solving my problem the link...

Comment: Please edit the question and explain the problem completely.

Comment: You should use a prepared statement with parameters rather than substituting `json_encode($_POST)` directly into the query.

Comment: I don't know testing the $_POST data in https://test2.com/api or how to testing? The file_get_contents is okay, it works, but I think empty the $_POST array.

Comment: Try: $postdata = json_encode( $_POST ); Not works.

Comment: Your code is correct according to the other question. Why do you think you'll get a different answer?

Comment: Dear Barmar, edited my question.

Comment: If you check the access log on the server, do you see the POST request?

Comment: How to check the access log?

Comment: I don't know, it's your webserver.

Comment: Dear Barmar, please see the log(s).

Comment: Solved. The https://test2.com/api change to https://test2.com/api/index.php. OMG. Thanks.

Comment: Something is sending a `GET` request before each `POST` request. Are you using the same script to send the request?

Comment: I think the redirects POST: test2.com/api -> test2.com/api/index.php (GET), the $_POST is empty.